# framework7-vue - using vue components

Tags: javascript, vue.js

I have a small project that I thought of using `framework7-vue`.
I have a simple `html` with all the `js` link in directly:

html:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="node_modules/axios/dist/axios.min.js"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="node_modules/lodash/lodash.min.js"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="node_modules/moment/moment.js"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="node_modules/vue/dist/vue.min.js"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="node_modules/framework7/dist/js/framework7.min.js"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="node_modules/framework7-vue/dist/framework7-vue.min.js"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="js/app.js"></script>
```

then `app.js`:

```
var $$ = Dom7;
Vue.use(Framework7Vue, Framework7,$$);

new Vue({
  el: '#app',
property, e.g.:
  framework7: {
    name: 'My App',
    id: 'com.myapp.test',
    panel: {
      swipe: 'left',
    },
  },
  data: function () {
    return {
      userrole:"admin",
    }
  },
  mounted () {
    var self = this;
    self.getParcels();
  },
  // App root methods
  methods: {
//...
}
})
```

everything works fine so far.
However if I want to use `vue component`, I am not sure how to include in. For example, if I want to use [vddl](https://github.com/hejianxian/vddl), I can use `nom install` to add it to my `node_modules`. but I am not sure how add to my `vue app`.

I tried `import`:

> Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected identifier

How can I resolve this?

Answer (score 0):

Are you building for cordova/phonegap platform? If so, which template are you currently using?

I’d recommend on switching to [this template](https://github.com/scriptPilot/app-framework).

As you read the readme of the template, you can do `npm install` for any package you want to add, such as moment, etc.

They have everything setup which is also ES6 compliance.

Also, this template is able to help you deploy to both ios and android platform easily.

PS: As for your error on import statement, I think it has something to do with your babel dependencies. It would give me more insight if you include your `package.json` as well.

Hope this helps.

Comment: no, I only build for web and use the plain vanilla js.

Comment: Ok sorry for being off the topic. But this is an issue related with ES6 syntax. You might need to npm install babel-preset-es2015 as well. If you can use import, move all your js imports like vue, moment, etc to use import statement as well.

Answer (score 0):

after npm install

In your app.js

```
import Vddl from 'vddl';
var $$ = Dom7;
Vue.use(Framework7Vue, Framework7,$$);
Vue.use(Vddl);

new Vue({
  el: '#app',
property, e.g.:
framework7: {
  ...
}
```

It's same as the [Vddl Usage](https://github.com/hejianxian/vddl)

I think your question is nothing about Framework7-vue,
It's about VueJs Components.
And as the error message saids, this is a SyntaxError, try to find it out, and good luck!